# customize color of item in kendo dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Is possible to change color of item that has disabled in kendo dropdownlist. I want to customize color of that item to let user know that item is disabled.
here is my code:

```
function DisableUserOfficeItem() {
    var officedropdowndata = officedropdown.dataSource.data();
    for (var i = 0; i < officedropdowndata.length; i++) {
        var active = officedropdowndata[i].OfficeActive;
        if (active === false) {
            $("#usrconfigoffice" + "_listbox .k-item")[i].disabled = true;
            $("#usrconfigoffice" + "_listbox .k-input")[i].css('color', '#c7c7cd'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize Dropdown Options using [Kendo template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview). Refer this Kendo Dropdown Customization [Example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/template)

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poojadhanani/9uhvmqxv/)

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
     dataTextField: "ProductName",
     dataValueField: "ProductID",
     template: $("#template").html(),
     dataSource: {
       transport: {
         read: {
           dataType: "jsonp",
           url: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
         }
       }
     },
     dataBound: function(e) {
       $(".DiscontinuedDisable").parent().click(false);
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
.DiscontinuedDisable {
  color: #777777
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.material.min.css">
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<input id="products" style="width: 100%" />

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
  #if(Discontinued){#
  <span class="DiscontinuedDisable">#: ProductName # </span> #}else{#
  <span>#: ProductName # </span> #}#
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally (typescript):

```
 $('#your-dropdown').kendoDropDownList({
    dataBound: function () {
       $(this.items()).each(function (index, item) {
          var model = $('#your-dropdown').data('kendoDropDownList').dataItem(index);
          $(item).css('background-color', model.bgcolor);
       });
    }
 });
```